# LDA Mahout only one topic

Tags: mahout, lda

I am trying to follow the example on using LDA on the Reuters data as indicated in the Mahout In Action book. However, regardless of the number of times I run it, I always get only one topic.

I ran the command as indicated:

```
mahout lda -i reuters-vectors/tf-vectors -o reuters-lda-sparse -k 10 -v 34262 -x 20 -ow
```

I got the number from running seqdumper. After the command has run, I run the LDAPrintTopics as indicated in the book and get the following:

```
Topic 0
===========
billion [p(billion|topic_0) = 0.04580929884162013
pct [p(pct|topic_0) = 0.043323700764985575
dlrs [p(dlrs|topic_0) = 0.031395871939373196
3 [p(3|topic_0) = 0.027311386657272094
1987 [p(1987|topic_0) = 0.025690077982656934
1 [p(1|topic_0) = 0.022727304049111215
reuter [p(reuter|topic_0) = 0.019572283708227903
mln [p(mln|topic_0) = 0.014569551610736616
april [p(april|topic_0) = 0.014453636611524965
march [p(march|topic_0) = 0.014359948846622552
```

Is there way to get more topics out of LDA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your command says -k 10 which specifies that there need to be 10 topics.

See this https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/latent-dirichlet-allocation.html

Try changing your data set, may be its too small to generate 10 different topics